# summation of elements of a 2D vector into a 1D vector. C++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Help me please.
Tell me how to sum each vector in a two-dimensional vector and write the result into a one-dimensional vector. On C++.
Input:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
```

Required Output:

> b = { 9, 12 }

I found how to sum all the elements in a 2D vector, but I don't know how to sum the vectors in an existing 2D vector and write the result to a 1D vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    std::vector<double> b;
    std::vector<int> v;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
        {
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: your `vector` contains `doubles`, so your sum should probably be a `double` as well.

Comment: Hint: You have one sum in the end, but wouldn't you need to calculate two sums? One for the first element of each inner vector and one for the second element of each inner vector?

Comment: It really is. Writing error.

Comment: your example input does not match your text. You are not summing one vector to get an entry of the result. You are summing elements of all vectors in `a` to get an etry of the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I assume that in the sums vector that you require, element in index `i`, is the sum of all elements in index `i` in the vectors in `a`. This requires that all elements in `a` have the same size.

**You can do it in the following way:**
Traverse the elements in `a`. For each element: traverse the element  (which is a vector itself) and sum element `i` into the `i`th bin of the output vector.

**Something like:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    size_t num_of_sums = a[0].size();   // we assume all elements in a have the same size
    std::vector<double> sums(num_of_sums);
    for (auto const & v : a)
    {
        assert(v.size() == num_of_sums);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_of_sums; j++)
        {
            sums[j] += v[j];
        }
    }
    for (auto d : sums)
    {
        std::cout << d << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
9, 12,
```

**Note** that my `sums` vector contains `double`s, like your input data (unlike your `sum` which is an `int` and seems improper to sum `double` values).

Answer (score 2):

This would do:

- Create a vector `b` of 2 elements.
- Walk each vector `v` in `a`, adding each number to `b`.
- `fmt` is a utility library that lets you easily print vectors.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/h6o9bdG7v)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    std::vector<double> b(2);

    for (const auto& v : a) {
        b[0] += v[0];
        b[1] += v[1];
    }
    fmt::print("{}", b);
}

// Output: [9, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };

    auto res = std::accumulate(a.begin(),a.end(),std::vector<double>{0.0,0.0},[](auto a,const auto& b){        
        a[0] += b[0];
        a[1] += b[1];
        return a;
    });
    for (const auto& r : res ) { std::cout << r << " ";}
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MfbTvbMK1)

The elements of `a` have to have all same size for this to work. I assumed they all have two elements, if not the adding of the two elements has to be replaced by a loop.